# Atom HTML preview doesn't update when CSS is changed

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

I'm using Atom and it's HTML preview feature. If I change my CSS file, nothing happens. But then if I go to my HTML file and make any change, even just adding a space somewhere, everything updates.

I've referenced my CSS file in my HTML file as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Help?

Comment: I don't have any problems with browsers. It's only a problem on the Atom html preview.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are making updates to your files but when you refresh the page in the browser, you are not seeing the style changes getting applied.

If that is the case, you can do a hard reload of the page by clicking Ctrl + F5

More information here: https://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/

Answer (score 0):

If your stylesheets are external file, then your browser may store it somewhere and loads the old content. If you use Google Chrome, then press F12, navigate mouse to refresh page button (with <- and ->) buttons and right click it, you will see options on how much you want to reload. :)

Is this what you asked?

Because this is what happens to me, when I do not reload the page completely.. Before it, no new content of externa files is updated.

Comment: Thanks for downvote ofc, but can you tell me, what is the problem?

Comment: Chrome and IE work fine. It's the html preview feature on Atom that isn't working properly. 

I also have another problem that may be related. Basically a have a drop down menu that should appear when I click on a link. It works but the very first time I click the link, the drop down menu appears but then it disappears after about 1 second. This problem again is isolated to the Atom html preview and is not a problem on Chrome or IE.

btw I didn't downvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

guys I closed and opened Atom and it fixed the updating problem but I've still got the drop down menu problem. I think I'll create a new post for that since it's probably code-related